# Compose a complex query in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, subquery, temporary-tables, union

I have a huge table like following:

```
CREATE TABLE public.huge_table (
    sampl_day date NOT NULL,
    tick_time timestamp(6) with time zone NOT NULL,
    crit_feat integer NOT NULL,
    ---
    --- other fields
    ---
    CONSTRAINT pkey_huge_table PRIMARY KEY (tick_time)
);
CREATE INDEX idx_huge_table_day_time
ON public.huge_table USING brin (sampl_day, tick_time);
```

This table stores much many samples(rows) of a time series, one row for one sample.
Most time, the field "crit_feat" has a very low value, for example 1 or 2.
At some abnormal time point, it would go very high, for example 100.

It's very easy to find out these special rows in a single query. Let's call them as "special time points".

And now I need to view rows those happened in 5s before/after each of above special time points in a query result set, to find out what happened before/after a special event.

If I only need to find out a single one such special time point and rows in 5s before/after it, it is relatively easier.

I can do like this:

```
WITH spec_time as (
    SELECT tick_time tp
    FROM huge_table
    ORDER BY crit_feat DESC LIMIT 1)

SELECT *
FROM huge_table
WHERE tick_time BETWEEN (SELECT tp FROM spec_time) - INTERVAL '5s'
                    AND (SELECT tp FROM spec_time) + INTERVAL '5s'
ORDER BY tick_time;
```

But I need to do so with every special points and `UNION` all of them!

The number of all speical points is about 20k at least, and the events that should be selected out are **NOT ONLY** whose "crit_feat" field has the largest value, **BUT ALSO** include ones with a value greater than a specified threshold, for example: the median value of "crit_feat" field within entire data set.

I guess that I can get it with Temporary-Table and Cursor in a Storage Procedure/Function, but I'm expecting a simpler method!

Sorry about my ugly English, I hope that I have expressed correctly things what I want to say.

Thanks!

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure if I understand you correctly, you can accomplish your goal with just a self join like so:

```
SELECT Results.* -- Don't actually use *, it's an anti-pattern. Instead, list out only the fields you need.
FROM huge_table AS Threshold
INNER JOIN huge_table AS Results
    ON Threshold.tick_time 
        BETWEEN 
            Results.tick_time - INTERVAL '5s'
            AND Results.tick_time + INTERVAL '5s'
WHERE Threshold.crit_feat >= 100 -- Input your threshold value here
```

You'll likely want an index minimally on `(tick_time, crit_feat)`.

Also, the above may return the same row from the `Results` instance of the table multiple times, if it matches on multiple rows from the `Threshold` instance of the table. If that's so, and you want the unique list of rows, you can just add the `DISTINCT` keyword after the `SELECT` keyword.

Comment: Your solution is perfect!  Thanks!

Comment: And would you please to explain me : Why should I make an index on `(tick_time, crit_feat)`, instead of `(crit_feat)`?  In my mind, it's enough to filter the data set on the alias `Threshold`. I have tested with both of two respectively. Of course, `(tick_time, crit_feat)` can be used with, and `(crit_feat)` can **NOT**.  I'm just wondering why.

Comment: @Leon No problem, glad to be of help! I'm guessing that `(tick_time, crit_feat)` is a good pick because it covers both use cases in the query: 1. the predicates used by `Threshold` which is both fields - one in the `INNER JOIN` and the other in the `WHERE` clause, and 2. the predicate used for `Results` which is just the `tick_time` field. An index on only `crit_feat` does not cover the `INNER JOIN` predicate using the `tick_time` field.

Comment: But when we are filtering `Threshold`, only field `crit_feat` will be checked, so an index only on it is nessary? As to `Results`, there is already an index(primary key) on it, enough to join it with `Threshold`.   I know I'm wrong, but I don't know why. haha!

Comment: @Leon "*But when we are filtering `Threshold`, only field `crit_feat` will be checked*" - Not true. A predicate for `tick_time` is applied against it also, for the `ON` clause of the `INNER JOIN` statement. The other existing index you have is on `(sampl_day, tick_time)` which means the index sorts on `sampl_day` first and then by `tick_time` next, like a phone book. Since you're not using `sampl_day` in the predicates, that index is not efficiently applicable to this query. It's not possible to seek through the first unused field, `sampl_day`, in order to seek on the second field `tick_time`.

Comment: Got it! I appreciate !!!